# $http provider makes external requests to Github API, but not Google map API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, httprequest

I'm trying to use AngularJS's $http provider to create a request to the Google Map API. I keep getting the error message:

```
use 'strict';

if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

  if (name) {
    return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
  }

  return headersObj;
}
```

I created an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/omniphx/dkagwpu0/16/

The request to the Github API will succeed, but the request to the Google map's API will fail. Can't figure out what I might be missing. Both seem to output JSON formats and both URLs work fine in my browser.

Anyone have an idea of what is causing the Google Maps API to fail?

Comment: 'fail' is a big word - how does it fail?

Comment: The HTTP Get request is failing. It's reproduced in the fiddle I created.

Comment: What's the status code (do bear in mind everything necessary to answer the question needs to be in the question, not on jsfiddle)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Status code = 0

Comment: maps API URL isn't returning CORS headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request isn't exactly *failing* per se. 
You are running into the classic CORS problem.

Found `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` in console.

Github has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header present in the header while googleapis doesn't has any such header. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. Do you happen to know if there any type of workaround?

Comment: Try if JSONP works. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp 
Take a look at the example there.